# Merge [casting] into [type-casting]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

The [casting](/questions/tagged/casting) and [type-casting](/questions/tagged/type-casting) tags cover the exact same ground as near as I can tell by going through several pages of each.  In any of the handful of languages I know, casting always deals with type.  Is there a narrow situation where one could not be replaced with the other?  (If so, we need to ferret those questions out and manually retag them.)

Even though [casting](/questions/tagged/casting) (×928) is currently more popular than [type-casting](/questions/tagged/type-casting) (×95), I prefer [type-casting](/questions/tagged/type-casting) for some reason.  Perhaps it's just a tad bit more explicit and conventional?

Could a moderator merge [casting](/questions/tagged/casting) into [type-casting](/questions/tagged/type-casting)?

Comment: don't forget  [ [typecast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typecast) ] - Also suggest / vote on synonyms.

Comment: @Peter: I suggested it as a [synonym for type-casting](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/type-casting/synonyms) just before posting. :)