# The synonym suggestion system confuses me

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, tags

I read **["How does the tag synonym suggestion feature work?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58023/how-does-the-tag-synonym-suggestion-feature-work)**, but I ran into what may be a problem or nothing at all.

`casting` is most used, so I suggested `type-casting` be a synonym.

Then I suggested `typecasting` also be a synonym, and I got a warning, since `typecasting` is already a synonym suggestion for `type-casting`.

If `type-casting` is accepted as a synonym for `casting`, does `typcasting` automatically become a synonym for `casting` too.

In other words, does it matter what order you suggest synonyms in?

---

[image]

Comment: If you believe [casting] is a better tag than [type-casting], could you [elaborate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64913/54262)?  I'm not strongly attached to one or the other, but given how close between my post and this, I am definitely curious.

Comment: @Gnome - I don't. I didn't realize it mattered which one you suggest a synonym to, since synonym means equal..... Also, you can't suggest `casting` as a synonym on the `type-casting` page, since `casting` is more frequent.

Comment: It slightly matters: the "master" tag is what gets used from that point forward and should be the "correct" name. Re the latter, that's why I had to post on Meta for a moderator to do the retag (they have tools to retag all at once) rather than just make a synonym suggestion.

Comment: @Gnome - Thanks. I see. I just didn't quite get the "master" tag concept.

Answer (score 1):

I believe no synonyms will change, but the tag can be rewritten multiple times. For example, if your proposal succeeds and `type-casting -> casting`, `typecasting -> type-casting` will still show up in the synonym list. Attempting to use the tag `typecasting` will result in the tag `casting`, since `typecasting -> type-casting -> casting`

Comment: So theoretically, it'd be bast to propose both `type-casting` and `typecasting` as synonyms on the `casting` page?

Comment: @Peter You can't, for the reason you said in the second half of your question